# Prestashop - how to create a button that opens custom page?

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to make a button 'Offer your price' which opens my custom page **'offer-price.tpl'**. The question is how can I open my custom offer-price page by clicking on the button(**product-offer-price.tpl**)? PS version 1.7

**OfferPriceController.php:**

```
<?php

class OfferPriceControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'offerprice';
    public $ssl = true;

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $this->setTemplate('offer-price');
    }
}
```

**offer-price.tpl:**

```
{extends file=$layout}
```

**product-offer-price.tpl:**

```
<div class="offer">
  <button
  class="btn btn-primary offer-price"
  data-button-action="offer-price"
  type="submit">
    {l s='Offer your price'}
  </button>
</div>
```

**product.tpl:**

```
{block name='offer_price'}
     {include file='catalog/_partials/product-offer-price.tpl'}
{/block}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to create new module to do it.